# Kibana-like tool for PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a tool that could browse and visualize data from db like Kibana does.

I'd prefer a native Posgres tool to any that transfers data from a db somewhere else. I know that rivers for Elasticsearch did the latter and it's now deprecated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not used it up to now, but I heard of it: https://github.com/getredash/redash

Answer (score 3):

## Free...

I'm not 100% sure that there's a good, free, open source alternative, if that's what you're looking for. The closest you are likely to find is [**Orange**](http://orange.biolab.si/), a data mining and visualization tool.  For a little bit of instruction, just do a little Googling, or consult helpful [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhC2ckTnEgU) such as the one linked.

## or Paid?

If you're willing to pay for it, I would highly recommend using [**Tableau**](http://www.tableau.com/).  They have a free version, called Tableau Public, which only works with flat files, but will allow you to do some basic testing. The licensed version allows native connections to many databases, including Postgres. Lastly, if you are a larger enterprise client who has a business model which permits cloud storage, [**Chartio**](https://chartio.com/) may also be a good alternative.

*Full disclosure*:  I have no business connections to any of the companies mentioned, and my post is meant to be purely informative and non-promotional for the companies listed.